# Can I use j2me app exactly on blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, j2mepolish

I have developed an app in j2me polish.This jar works perfectly fine on other devices. I want this exact app to work on blackberry. My app uses internet connection so I created 3 different jars for GPRS, WI-FI and BIS. These 3 work fine but I want only one jar that should connect directly to the available network. I tried HttpConnectionFactory, ConnectionFactory. But I am not able to compile properly as I am getting error in j2mepolish classes.
I am developing app in eclipse. Can I use app developed using j2me polish in blackberry device?